# How do I get Dired to not display certain files?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dired

For instance I'd like it to not display all files that match the pattern `*~`

EDIT: The below worked:

```
(add-hook 'dired-load-hook
      (lambda ()
        (load "dired-x")
        ;; Set dired-x global variables here.  For example:
        ;; (setq dired-guess-shell-gnutar "gtar")
        ;; (setq dired-x-hands-off-my-keys nil)
        ))
(setq dired-omit-files "^#\\|~$")
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        ;; Set dired-x buffer-local variables here.  For example:
        (dired-omit-mode 1)
        ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use dired-x, [read here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/dired-x/Omitting-Files-in-Dired.html), or fir dired, read [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.help/browse_thread/thread/acb20ee78c00e4ec).  In the case of dired, the suggested solution takes a regex that would filter out what is to be shown and displays only those files.  This could be a bit tricky in your case.

Comment: You can call dired with a regexp like this: `/tmp/*[!~]`. This example will list `/tmp` without filenames ending in `~`

Answer (score 1):

Answered over on SuperUser, but I'll answer here, too.  Use `dired-omit`:

```
Dired-Omit minor mode (indicator Omit):
Toggle Dired-Omit mode.
With numeric ARG, enable Dired-Omit mode if ARG is positive, disable
otherwise.  Enabling and disabling is buffer-local.
If enabled, "uninteresting" files are not listed.
Uninteresting files are those whose filenames match regexp `dired-omit-files',
plus those ending with extensions in `dired-omit-extensions'.
```

`dired-omit` is part of `dired-x`.